# How to Turn Off SFCGAL Geometry Validation?

Tags: sfcgal

SFCGAL documentation (https://oslandia.github.io/SFCGAL/documentation.html)
states that all geometry processing algorithms by default check the validity of input geometries, but also come in a second variant "where no actual check is made (taking a NoValidityCheck tag as additional parameter)".

However, I can't find any examples or detailed documentation for queries that use a NoValidityCheck tag.

What is the syntax for this and does it actually work with the SFCGAL extension to postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that the documentation is old and the function versions allowing the NoValidityCheck have not been implemented.